# How to cancel computation in another Isolate

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to process a sequence of images in another Isolate, I tried to use `compute()` method provided by the Flutter foundation library to do the job, but once it spawned it doesn't seem to stop even if I lose the reference to it, like if the widget that calling the operation is disposed.

I also have tried to spawn the isolate myself, using `Isolate.spawn()` and send message between Isolate using `SendPort`, but the second Isolate that do the computation doesn't seem to listen messages being sent to it while it's computing.

Is there a way to start an isolated computation that is cancelable?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Isolate.kill`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-isolate/Isolate/kill.html). From the documentation:

> Requests the isolate to shut down.

Comment: Once it reached critical computation, it won't listen any message I send. The message is only being processed after the computation is done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in that case the compute function is not the best option for your need since you don't have full control of the isolate. Can you try to implementing using the `Isolate.spawn` instead? Actually I recommend you the plugin easy_isolate, it provides an easy way to work with isolates with well-explained documentation.

This is the scaffold using the easy_isolate plugin, and you can call `worker.dispose()` to kill the isolate. Also, remember to use async operations when possible, which will avoid freezing the thread.

```
void main() async {
  final worker = Worker();
  await worker.init(mainHandler, isolateHandler);
  
  worker.sendMessage(null);
}

void mainHandler(dynamic data, SendPort isolateSendPort) {
  isolateSendPort.send(null);
}

// Top-level function (or static)
void isolateHandler(dynamic data, SendPort mainSendPort, SendErrorFunction onSendError) {
  mainSendPort.send(null);
}
```